# An average estimate

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

In the paper [here](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~lwang/cccalderon.pdf) ,which the aim is to prove the Calderor-Zygmund theorem with a new approach 
 in the lemma 7, page 8 we have
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{|B_4|}\int_{B_4} | D^2u|^2 \le 2^n \ \ \mbox{and}\ \ \dfrac{1}{|B_4|} \int_{B_4} |f|^2 \le 2^n \delta^2
\end{equation}
Then 
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{|B_4|}\int_{B_4}| \nabla u -(\overline{\nabla}u)_{B_4}|^2 \le C_1
\end{equation}
where $\Delta u = f $ and $f_{B_r}=\dfrac{1}{|B_r|} \int_{B_r}f$ and $C_1$ is a universal constant. I can't understand the last estimate. I think that this can follows only on the first estimate above.

Comment: I think that just follows from the Poincare identity, right? I don't think it has anything to do with $f$, just that the integral of $\nabla u$ minus its average squared is bounded by the integral of $D^2 u$ squared.